# How to query a JSONB array?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table

`Visitor: (id, .., custom::jsonb[])`

`custom` is an array of JSON objects of the form `{field:string, value:string}`. Example:

`{"field": "apps_created", "value": "3"}`

Say I want to find all the `Visitors` with 3 or more `apps_created`, how would I go about this? Note: every `Visitor` can have different fields and often there is not overlap with other visitors.

I've tried to consult the postgres documentation or other stackoverflow questions, but I have a hard time figuring out what functions/operators are used in this situation.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: you could make life a lot easier by storing {'apps_created': '3'} ie drop the 'field' and 'value' from each dictionary so that instead of a dictionary with two elements you have a dictionary with one. In fact if you did this you might be able to chuck the whole array of dictionaries thing and have a large dictionary which would be so much easier to work with in postgresql  and in your code

Comment: The reason for storing it that way is because I let users submit custom data fields/values and hence cannot know them at design time. AFAIK this is not possible when hardcoding the key like that

Comment: With my suggestion you still don't need to know what those fields are at design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from visitor
where
  exists (
    select 1 
    from unnest(custom) t(x) 
    where x->>'field' = 'apps_created' and (x->>'value')::int >= 3);
```

---

Upd
However the classic way to implement such things in relational databases is (schematic):

```
create table entity (
  entity_id serial not null primary key,
  ...);

create table param (
  param_id serial not null primary key,
  param_name varchar not null unique,
  ...);

create table param_value (
  param_id int references param(param_id),
  entity_id int references entity(entity_id) on delete cascade,
  value varchar,
  ...
  primary key (param_id, entity_id));
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Can you explain the `t(x)` syntax? I figure that it maps x to each element of the array, but a brief elaboration would be much appreciated

Comment: Also, with regards to indexing this query, is a GIN index on field and then value the way to go?

Comment: @Tarlen 1) It is standard syntax for subqueries in the from clause, where `t` is an alias for subquery and optional aliases for fields in brackets: `... from (select 1 as x) t` or `... from (select 1) t(x)`. In our case `unnest (custom)` is equal to `(select unnest(custom))`; 2) I'v never used GIN indexes.